# Why does Webpack command take so long even though I excluded node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

I have been trying to learn React and Webpack from [ReactJS Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b).
My issue is when I run webpack from within the top level directory of all my files, it takes usually around **62392ms**. However, in the tutorials his takes **1394ms**. I've read that having **exclude**'s should help increase performance time, but I already have excluded **node_modules**. I've tried switching my **loader** to just **babel** and it brought my webpack time down to **13183ms**, but that still seems awfully slow, especially when it's only transpiling one file(**client.js**). Is there anyone who knows why running the webpack command is so slow, as most of the other stackoverflow answers seem to point to include/excluding paths/directories and I've already done that?

My file structure is as below:

```
node_modules
src
->  js
->->    client.js
->  client.min.js
->  index.html
.gitignore
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/src",
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        target: 'node',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        //include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

And my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "module-loaders",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Learning React and Webpack through LearnCode.academy",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/dustinchang/React_Learning_LearnCode.Academy.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/dustinchang/React_Learning_LearnCode.Academy/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/dustinchang/React_Learning_LearnCode.Academy#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

I greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: sourcemap -> slow, babel -> slow, UglifyJsPlugin -> slow. Try to run webpack --json --progress --profile > stats.json and load it into the analyse tool to see more details

Comment: You say the tutorial is faster than you project: What the difference between them? If you have far more files than the tutorial project and more dependencies too, it could explain the difference.

Comment: The only dependencies differences are I added babel-core as I read somewhere to try using just babel instead of babel-loader, which did somewhat improve performance, but still is slow, and then webpack-dev-server which is just a bit further in the tutorial.

Comment: Are you setting the proper value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` in development version?

Comment: I don't believe so, the only time the tutorial did something like that was in the command line saying `process.env.NODE_ENV=production` webpack, but other than that we've just been using webpack, so I didn't think I had to.

Comment: @TobiasK. Sorry did not see your comment. I tried the analyzer, and it came out as my client.js being 50276 ms. Is there any reason that it is taking so long as the client.js is basically just a Hello World Component in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can activate the cache directory babel option](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options). It saves me a lot of time when reloading.

Comment: I take it, that it does not work on MacOS then, as I get an error if I switch to using babel-loader?cacheDirectory.